# Routing does not work properly in laravel

Tags: laravel, web, laravel-6

I am working on my web project that is written in laravel and there are some problems with my routing and session.I found no errors on the screen but sometime routing are wrong.
For example : I go to \user\chat and it goes to another route but it does not happen every time. Sometimes it goes to wrong route and sometimes it goes to the correct route. I think there might be some problems with my sessions. I have four guard for admin,user,company and writer.
I am looking for some things to debug these kinds of errors in my project or can someone tell me where should I check such kind of problems. 
Sorry for not including code segments. I don't know which part should be shown.

This is web.php.

```
    Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
Route::get('/login', function () {
    return redirect('/home');
})->name('login');

Route::get('/debug-sentry', function () {
    throw new Exception('My first Sentry error!');
});


// Routes for client
Route::prefix('/company')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\CompanyLoginController@showCompanyLoginForm')->name('company.login');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\CompanyLoginController@companyLogin')->name('company.login.submit');
    Route::get('/register', 'Auth\CompanyRegisterController@showCompanyRegisterForm')->name('company.register');
    Route::post('/register', 'Auth\CompanyRegisterController@add_company')->name('add_company');
    Route::get('/logout','Auth\CompanyLoginController@logout')->name('company.logout');

    Route::get('/company_profile', 'CompanyController@profile')->name('company.profile');
    Route::get('/company_profile/{id}', 'Database\CompanyController@edit');
    Route::post('/company_profile/{id}', 'Database\CompanyController@update')->name('update_company');

    Route::post('/chat', 'CompanyController@chat')->name('company.chat');
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return redirect()->route('company.profile');
    });
});
Route::prefix('/user')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\UserLoginController@showUserLoginForm')->name('user.login');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\UserLoginController@userLogin')->name('user.login.submit');
    Route::get('/register', 'Auth\UserRegisterController@showUserRegisterForm')->name('user.register');
    Route::post('/register', 'Auth\UserRegisterController@createUser')->name('user.register');
    Route::get('/logout','Auth\UserLoginController@logout')->name('user.logout');
    Route::post('/chat', 'UserController@chat')->name('user.chat');
    Route::post('/createCon', 'UserController@createcon')->name('user.createcon');
    Route::post('/createConPre', 'UserController@createconpre')->name('user.createconpre');
    Route::get('/my_account', 'UserController@profile')->name('user.profile');
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return redirect()->route('user.profile');
    });
   //
    Route::post('/add','UserController@add_to_cart')->name('add_to_cart');
    Route::post('/fileupload','UserController@fileupload')->name('file_upload');

});



// Routes for client site
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/home');
})->name('home');


Route::prefix('/home')->group(function () {
    /*Route::get('/', function () {
        return View::make('client.pages.index');
    });*/
    Route::get('/cart','UserController@view_cart');
    Route::get('/minicart','UserController@minicart');
    Route::get('wishlist','UserController@view_wishlist')->name('wishlist');

    Route::get('/', 'Database\ProductController@view_index');
    // Route::get('chat', function () {
    //  return View::make('client.pages.chat');
    // });
    // Route::get('blog-details', function () {
    //     return View::make('client.pages.blog-details');
    // });
    Route::post('/fileUpload', 'HomeController@fileupload')->name('file_upload');
    Route::get('contact-us', function () {
        return View::make('client.pages.contact-us');
    });
   /* Route::get('login-register', function () {
        return View::make('client.pages.login-register');
    });*/

    Route::prefix('premium_show')->group(function(){
        Route::get('/',"Database\PremiumController@view_premium_c");
        Route::get('/detail/{id}',"Database\PremiumController@view_premium_c_dtl");
    });
    Route::get('recover_account', function () {
        return View::make('client.pages.recover_account');
    });

    Route::get('supplier',"Database\CompanyController@view_company_c");
    Route::get('company_profile/{id}', "Database\CompanyController@company_detail_c");

    Route::get('supplier_company', function () {
        return View::make('client.pages.supplier_company');
    });
    Route::prefix('trade_show')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', "Database\BlogController@view_blog");
        Route::get('view/{id}', 'Database\BlogController@view_blog_detail')->name('blog_detail');
    });
    Route::prefix('shop')->group(function () {
        Route::get('', 'Database\ProductController@view_product');
        Route::get('view', 'Database\ProductController@view_product')->name('view_product_user');
        Route::get('/{id}','Database\ProductController@view_product_dtl');

        Route::get('/category/{category}','Database\ProductController@view_product_by_category');
        Route::get('/jewellery/{jewellery}','Database\ProductController@view_product_by_jewellery');
        Route::get('/add_to_wishlist/{id}','UserController@add_to_wishlist')->name('add_to_wish');
        Route::get('delete/{id}', "UserController@delete_wishlist")->name('delete_wishlist');
    });
    Route::prefix('login')->group(function () {
        Route::get('', function () {
            return View::make('client.pages.login');
        })->name('add_user');

        Route::post('', "Database\UserController@add_user");
    });
});

Route::prefix('/writer')->group(function(){
      Route::prefix('blog')->group(function () {
        Route::get('', function () {
            return redirect()->route('view_blog');
        });
        Route::get('view', 'Database\BlogController@view_blog')->name('view_blog');

        Route::get('add', function () {
            return View::make('admin.pages.add-blog');
        })->name('add_blog');
        Route::post('add', "Database\BlogController@add_blog");
        Route::get('view/{id}', 'Database\BlogController@view_blog_detail');
        Route::get('edit/{id}',"Database\BlogController@edit_blog");
        Route::post('edit', "Database\BlogController@update_blog")->name('edit_blog');

        Route::get('delete/{id}', "Database\BlogController@delete_blog")->name('delete_blog');
    });
    Route::prefix('/product')->group(function(){
        Route::get('', function () {
            return redirect()->route('view_product');
        });
        Route::get('view', 'Database\ProductController@view_product')->name('view_product');
        Route::get('view/{id}', 'Database\ProductController@view_product_dtl');
        Route::get('add', "Database\ProductController@add")->name('add_product');
        Route::post('add', "Database\ProductController@add_product");

        Route::get('edit/{id}',"Database\ProductController@edit_product");
        Route::post('edit', "Database\ProductController@update_product")->name('edit_product');

        Route::get('delete/{id}', "Database\ProductController@delete_product")->name('delete_product');
    });
});

Route::prefix('/admin')->group(function(){

    Route::get('/register', 'Auth\AdminRegisterController@showAdminRegisterForm')->name('admin.register');
    Route::post('/register', 'Auth\AdminRegisterController@createAdmin')->name('admin.register');
    Route::get('/login','Auth\AdminLoginController@showAdminLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('/login','Auth\AdminLoginController@adminLogin')->name('admin.login.submit');
    Route::get('/logout','Auth\AdminLoginController@logout')->name('admin.logout');
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return redirect()->route('admin.home');
    });
    Route::get('index', function () {
        return redirect()->route('admin.home');
    })->name('admin.index');
    Route::get('/home','AdminController@index')->name('admin.home');
    Route::post('/chat', 'AdminController@chat')->name('admin.chat');
    // Route::get('chat', function () {
    //  return View::make('admin.pages.chat');
    // });

    Route::get('company_lists', function () {
        return View::make('admin.pages.company_lists');
    });
    Route::get('company_lists',"Database\CompanyController@view_company");
    Route::get('delete/{id}', "Database\CompanyController@delete_company")->name('delete_company');
    Route::get('company_detail/{id}',"Database\CompanyController@company_detail");

    Route::get('edit_products', function () {
        return View::make('admin.pages.edit_products');
    });

    Route::get('my_account', function () {
        return View::make('admin.pages.my_account');
    });
    Route::get('order_lists', function () {
        return View::make('admin.pages.order_lists');
    });
    Route::get('product_payment', function () {
        return View::make('admin.pages.product_payment');
    });
    Route::get('profile', 'Database\AdminController@view_admin');
    Route::get('table-data-table', function () {
        return View::make('admin.pages.table-data-table');
    });

       Route::prefix('user_lists')->group(function () {
        Route::get('', function () {
            return redirect()->route('view_users');
        });
        Route::get('view', 'Database\UserController@view_users')->name('view_users');
        Route::get('view/{id}', 'Database\UserController@view_user');
        Route::get('delete/{id}', "Database\UserController@delete_user")->name('delete_user');
    });
    Route::prefix('product')->group(function () {
        Route::get('', function () {
            return redirect()->route('view_product');
        });
        Route::get('view', 'Database\ProductController@view_product')->name('view_product');
        Route::get('view/{id}', 'Database\ProductController@view_product_dtl');
        /*Route::get('add', function () {
            //return View::make('admin.pages.add-product');
            return view('admin.pages.add-product');
        })->name('add_product');*/
        Route::get('add', "Database\ProductController@add")->name('add_product');
        Route::post('add', "Database\ProductController@add_product");

        Route::get('edit/{id}',"Database\ProductController@edit_product");
        Route::post('edit', "Database\ProductController@update_product")->name('edit_product');

        Route::get('delete/{id}', "Database\ProductController@delete_product")->name('delete_product');
    });
    Route::get('company_lists',"Database\CompanyController@view_company");
    Route::prefix('blog')->group(function () {
        Route::get('', function () {
            return redirect()->route('view_blog');
        });
        Route::get('view', 'Database\BlogController@view_blog')->name('view_blog');

        Route::get('add', function () {
            return View::make('admin.pages.add-blog');
        })->name('add_blog');
        Route::post('add', "Database\BlogController@add_blog");
        Route::get('view/{id}', 'Database\BlogController@view_blog_detail');
        Route::get('edit/{id}',"Database\BlogController@edit_blog");
        Route::post('edit', "Database\BlogController@update_blog")->name('edit_blog');

        Route::get('delete/{id}', "Database\BlogController@delete_blog")->name('delete_blog');
    });
       Route::prefix('premium')->group(function () {
        Route::get('', function () {
            return redirect()->route('view_premium');
        });
        Route::get('view', 'Database\PremiumController@view_premium')->name('view_premium');
        Route::get('add', function () {
            return View::make('admin.pages.add-premium');
        })->name('add_premium');
        Route::post('add', "Database\PremiumController@add_premium");
        Route::get('detail/{id}',"Database\PremiumController@premium_detail");
        Route::get('edit/{id}',"Database\PremiumController@edit_premium");
        Route::post('edit', "Database\PremiumController@update_premium")->name('update_premium');

        Route::get('delete/{id}', "Database\PremiumController@delete_premium")->name('delete_premium');
    });
       Route::prefix('writer')->group(function () {
        Route::get('', function () {
            return redirect()->route('view_writer');
        });
        Route::get('view', 'Database\WriterController@view_writer')->name('view_writer');
        Route::get('add', function () {
            return View::make('admin.pages.add-writer');
        })->name('add_writer');
        Route::post('add', "Database\WriterController@add_writer");
        Route::get('edit/{id}',"Database\WriterController@edit_writer");
        Route::post('edit', "Database\WriterController@update_writer")->name('update_writer');

        Route::get('delete/{id}', "Database\WriterController@delete_writer")->name('delete_writer');
    });
});
Route::prefix('writer')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/login','Auth\WriterLoginController@showWriterLoginForm')->name('writer.login');
    Route::post('/login','Auth\WriterLoginController@writerLogin')->name('writer.login.submit');
    Route::post('/logout','Auth\WriterLoginController@logout')->name('writers.logout');
    Route::get('/logout','Auth\WriterLoginController@logout')->name('writer.logout');
    Route::get('/home','WriterController@index')->name('writer.home');
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return redirect()->route('writer.home');
    });
    Route::get('/index', function () {
        return redirect()->route('writer.home');
    });
    });

Route::post('/check_out', 'PaymentController@check_out');
Route::get('/check_out', 'PaymentController@check_out');
Route::get('/check_out', function() {
    return view('payment.check_out');
});
```

This is auth.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'writer' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'writers',
        ],
        'company' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'companies',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
         'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],
        'writers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Writer::class,
        ],
        'companies' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Company::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        'writers' => [
            'provider' => 'writers',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        'companies' => [
            'provider' => 'companies',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

Comment: Try posting the `routes/web.php` code with `guard` code you have implemented in order to track the problem easily

Comment: I uploaded my codes and thank for reviewing.